# question about lm function in R

Tags: r, interaction, lm

I have a simple question to ask regarding the lm function (and linear models in general). I am trying to predict y based on x, z, and a x*z interaction. If I simply predict y based on x I get the following output

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -0.2265     1.3192  -0.172   0.8659  
X          -0.6510     0.3547  -1.835   0.0864
```

but when I add the other terms and their interaction I get different output for X

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -4.416      6.001  -0.736    0.475
X            1.365      2.135   0.639    0.534
Z            7.756      9.591   0.809    0.433
X:Z       -3.281      3.317  -0.989    0.341
```

Can someone briefly explain why this is? Thanks

Comment: X is correlated with Z and/or the product of X and Z. Thus, the effect of X will change.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you want to use (logistic) regression to predict if it is going to snow on the following day. You start with no prior knowledge beyond the fact that it snows only during 5% of days, that's your intercept term. Then your friend tells you that he are ice cream yesterday, you can treat this as first feature for the model, that decreases the pedicted probability of snow. You also learn that it is cold outside, it makes the chance of snow higher, but the information about ice creams now feel somehow less important (so their "weight" decreases). Next your friend tells you, "by the way, did you know that we have this tradition with my wife, that we eat ice cream at the middle of the winter". This new information is a plot twist, now the information about ice cream is important again! Same things happen in regression, where all the information is considered *together*, rather then independently of each other.